# Naming a database, based on an input

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm sure this is either impossible, or really easy, but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to name a database based on an input. To sum it up very quickly:

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime

global date
d = datetime.datetime.today()
month = str(d.month)
day = str(d.day)
year = str(d.year)
date = month+day+year

print(type(date))
def name_creation():
    while True:
        global name
        name = input("What is the name? ")
        answer = input("Is the name correct?(y/n)")
        if answer not in ('y', 'n'):
            print ("Invalid input")
            name_creation()
            break
        if answer == 'y':
            break
        if answer == 'n':
            print ("Okay, re-enter name.")
    global name_date
    name_date = name + " " + date
name_creation()
conn = sqlite3.connect (eval(name_date).db)
```

most of this isn't important, but I've been trying to fix this for around 2 weeks. I'm sure I'm going about this all of the wrong way, but I can't find the problem so i can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define name_date out of of the function to use it as global.

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
name_date=''
.
.
.
.
def name_creation():
.
. 
  global name_date
  name_date="type_your_text_here"
conn = sqlite3.connect (eval(name_date).db)
```

Or you could just make it return that name_date and then use it in creating a conn.

And try naming a db like this:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect(name_date + ".db")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured it was something simple. This is my first time using Python in a couple year, so I have forgotten quite a bit.